# eemeir package fails to use correct gender by default

Tags: eemeir, he-she

If there's a better package to handle this than [`eemeir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eemeir), I haven't found it yet. I looked at [`he-she`](http://ctan.org/pkg/he-she), but I don't really want to alternate, I just want to be able to quickly change the gender of pronouns for different people in a text (for example, a student, a parent, etc.).

`eemeir`'s documentation seems to indicate that defining a new word pair will make the neutral form of the word a valid command with correct gender assignment, but it appears to use the default gender instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[female]{eemeir}

\begin{document}

\newwordpair{\child}{son}{daughter}
\male[child]

Why does \verb|\child| return \child (using the default gender),
but \verb|\child[child]| returns \child[child] (using the assigned gender)?

\end{document}
```

Any ideas? Or suggestions on adapting `he-she` to my use?

Answer (score 3):

This is how the package works. After

```
\newwordpair{\child}{son}{daughter}
```

the expansion of `\child` ends with `\@eemeirword` which is a command with an optional argument (and empty default).

If you call `\child` you end up the package macros examining `\ifmale` which, in your example, is false because of the package option. If you call `\child[foo]` the conditional `\ifmalefoo` is examined. This conditional is set up either with `\male[foo]` or `\female[foo]`.

Instead of `\male[child]` you should issue something like

```
\male[XY]
```

so that you can call `\child[XY]` and use `XY` for all word pairs.

Here's an example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[female]{eemeir}

\begin{document}

\newwordpair{\child}{son}{daughter}
\newwordpair{\parent}{father}{mother}
\male[XY]
\female[XX]

\verb|\child| returns \child (which should be feminine)

\verb|\parent| returns \parent (which should be feminine)

\verb|\child[XY]| returns \child[XY] (which should be masculine)

\verb|\parent[XY]| returns \parent[XY] (which should be masculine)

\bigskip
\swapgender

Now genders are swapped

\bigskip

\verb|\child| returns \child (which should be masculine)

\verb|\parent| returns \parent (which should be masculine)

\verb|\child[XX]| returns \child[XX] (which should be feminine)

\verb|\parent[XX]| returns \parent[XX] (which should be feminine)

\end{document}
```

[image]